# Pass variable (non-model-field) to serializer in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

I added a non model field to my serializer but after I hit api it returns the field as None value it doesn't store the value to use it in serializer function

serializers.py

```
class LeaveTeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'user_id', 'players']

    def get_user_id(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = None  # kwargs['context']['request'].user_id
        return user_id # user_id it's not who did the request it is other user_id

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_id = validated_data.get('user_id')
        user = self.context['request'].user

        if user_id is None or user_id == '':
            instance.players.remove(user)
        else:
            instance.players.remove(user_id)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class LeaveTeamListAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LeaveTeamSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Team.objects.filter(players=self.request.user) and Team.objects.filter(admin=self.request.user)
```

json put request

```
{
    "user_id":"22",
    "name":"a"
}
```

what i need is retrieve user_id (not the user who did the request but it is other user_id) value from json request as above json code to serializer class to use it in if statement.

please any one has the solution help me 
I tried to over ride the context but it didnt work fine with me

thanks

**Edit**

```
`class LeaveTeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'user_id', 'players']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_id = self.user_id
        print(user_id)        
        user = self.context['request'].user

        if user_id is None or user_id == '':
            instance.players.remove(user)
        else:
            instance.players.remove(user_id)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

`

Comment: `SerializerMethodField` is for read-only fields. It cannot be used to access data that you POST/PUT to a view. But you do not need to add a field. As @Linovia mentions, you can access anything in the request -- such as `request.user`, or `request.POST['user_id']` -- by accessing the context in the serializer, as you already do.

Comment: I tried your answer but `request.POST['user_id']`  gives me this error `'dict' object has no attribute 'POST'` , BTW user_id is not the the user who request but the user who request will add other user_id, if that wasn't clear

Comment: Sorry, what about `request.data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`serializers.CharField()`** instead of **`serializers.SerializerMethodField()`** along with **`write_only=True`** flag as

```
class LeaveTeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    # .... your code
```

**Note**: Don't forgot to remove **`get_user_id()`** method from your current code snippet

Comment: thank you for your answer,but i tried what you said as following 

`user_id = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)`
and in `def update`
 `user_id = self.user_id`
        `print(user_id)`

it raised error :
'LeaveTeamSerializer' object has no attribute 'user_id'

and i removed `def get_user_id:`

Comment: `self.user_id` is not in your OP. Pleas add the ***updated code***

Comment: @hishamDigital use `validated_data.pop('user_id')` instead of `self.user_id`

Comment: many thanks @JPG it works with me fine by your answer and i added `self` before `validated_data.pop('user_id')` and worked fine 

really many thanks